# Cannot update VSCode in WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been using VSCode within WSL without any issues so far. As of today I'm getting the following error

```
Updating VS Code Server to version 441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf)
Downloading: 100%
Failed
--2023-02-13 16:23:45--  https://update.code.visualstudio.com /commit:441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf/server-linux-x64/stable
Resolving update.code.visualstudio.com (update.code.visualstudio.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘update.code.visualstudio.com’
ERROR: Failed to download https://update.code.visualstudio.com   /commit:441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf/server-linux-x64/stable to /home/tim/.vscode-server/bin/441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf-1676301825.tar.gz
```

Seems that I cannot resolve `update.code.visualstudio.com` from within WSL anymore

```
ping update.code.visualstudio.com
ping: update.code.visualstudio.com: Name or service not known
```

`nslookup` shows the following output:

```
nslookup update.code.visualstudio.com
Server:         172.31.96.1
Address:        172.31.96.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
update.code.visualstudio.com    canonical name = vscode-update.trafficmanager.net.
vscode-update.trafficmanager.net        canonical name = vscode-update-weu.azurewebsites.net.
vscode-update-weu.azurewebsites.net     canonical name = waws-prod-am2-193.sip.azurewebsites.windows.net.
waws-prod-am2-193.sip.azurewebsites.windows.net canonical name = waws-prod-am2-193-temp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com.
```

- Within Windows I can successfully ping `update.code.visualstudio.com`
- I've stopped and started WSL
- I've rebooted my system
- No change, update suddenly doesn't work anymore
- I haven't added any proxies

Comment: Related github issue: [Error when updating VS Code Server on WSL2 / Ubuntu #102284](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102284) and related question on superuser.com: [VS Code insiders : Server download failed](https://superuser.com/q/1444427/1749748). Also possibly related: [VSCode | The editor cannot be opened due to an unexpected error](/q/72615537)

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable my `ufw` temporarily to get it to work.

`sudo ufw disable`

After than VSCode downloaded fine.

Re-enabled your ufw (if needed) after